# How do I merge dictionaries together in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d3 = dict(d1, **d2)
```

I understand that this merges the dictionary. But, is it unique? What if d1 has the same key as d2 but different value?  I would like d1 and d2 to be merged, but d1 has priority if there is duplicate key.

Comment: Please be aware that this trick is considered an abuse of `**` keyword argument passing unless all keys of `d2` are strings.  If not all keys of `d2` are strings, this fails in Python 3.2, and in alternative implementations of Python like Jython, IronPython and PyPy.  See, for example, http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099459.html .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You can use the [`.update()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method if you don't need the original `d2` any more:

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, **overwriting existing keys**. Return `None`.

E.g.:

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2} 
>>> d2 = {'b': 1, 'c': 3}
>>> d2.update(d1)
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

**Update:**

Of course you can copy the dictionary first in order to create a new merged one. This might or might not be necessary. In case you have compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances) in your dictionary, [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) should also be considered.

Comment: With this case d1 elements should correctly get priority if conflicting keys are found

Comment: In case you still need it, just make a copy.
d3 = d2.copy()
d3.update(d1)
but I would like to see d1 + d2 being added to the language.

Comment: d1 + d2 is problematic because one dictionary has to have priority during conflicts, and it's not particularly obvious which one.

Comment: d1 + d2 will only ever be implemented if Python gains a multimap, otherwise the ambiguity to the user is too confusing for the 8 byte typing gain.

Comment: You have objects in the dictionary in this example: `isinstance(int, object) is True` yet `deepcopy` doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: +1 for `copy.deepcopy`. @AntonyHatchkins `int` and `str`, while technically `objects`, generally have true copies made, but other objects (`list`, `dict`, any user-defined classes, etc) will only have shallow copies made unless `deepcopy` is called. Up to the user and the scenario which is preferred (shallow-vs-deep).

Comment: @dwanderson Yes, I'm aware of that. But "In case you have objects in your dictionary, `copy.deepcopy` should also be considered." part is incorrect and should be reworded.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins there's nothing incorrect about *considering* `deepcopy`, depending on your needs. It's totally valid and appropriate to mention here. Maybe you want it to say "in case you have more complex objects [...]"?

Comment: @dwanderson yes, this second part is correct. First part needs rewording.

Comment: @dwanderson I've made the necessary fix.

Answer (score 46):

In Python2,

```
d1={'a':1,'b':2}
d2={'a':10,'c':3}
```

d1 overrides d2:

```
dict(d2,**d1)
# {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

d2 overrides d1:

```
dict(d1,**d2)
# {'a': 10, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

This behavior is not just a fluke of implementation; it is guaranteed [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> If a key is specified both in the
>   positional argument and as a keyword
>   argument, the value associated with
>   the keyword is retained in the
>   dictionary.

Comment: Your examples will fail (producing a TypeError) in Python 3.2, and in current versions of Jython, PyPy and IronPython:  for those versions of Python, when passing a dict with the `**` notation, all the keys of that dict should be strings.  See the python-dev thread starting at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099427.html for more.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the heads up. I've edited the code to make it compatible with non-CPython implementations.

Comment: it fails if your keys are tuples of strings and numbers. for eg.   d1={(1,'a'):1, (1,'b'):0,}
d2={(1,'a'):1, (2,'b'):2, (2,'a'):1,}

Comment: Regarding the unpacking syntax, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/1959808) for changes forthcoming in python 3.5.

Comment: I was going to say that `d = dict(**d1, **d2)` works, but that's what @IoannisFilippidis references in their comment. Perhaps including the snippet here would've been clearer, so here it is.

Comment: asterisks explained - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Answer (score 23):

Starting in `Python 3.9`, the operator [`|`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) creates a new dictionary with the merged keys and values from two dictionaries:

```
# d1 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
# d2 = { 'b': 1, 'c': 3 }
d3 = d2 | d1
# d3: {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
```

This:

> Creates a new dictionary d3 with the merged keys and values of d2 and d1. The values of d1 take priority when d2 and d1 share keys.

---

Also note the `|=` operator which modifies d2 by merging d1 in, with priority on d1 values:

```
# d1 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
# d2 = { 'b': 1, 'c': 3 }
d2 |= d1
# d2: {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn't know that works yet, but it is a very convenient way of merging two dicts, definitely an easy one to remember for me ^^

Answer (score 15):

If you want `d1` to have priority in the conflicts, do:

```
d3 = d2.copy()
d3.update(d1)
```

Otherwise, reverse `d2` and `d1`.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to define a *merge* function. It's not sophisticated and just cost one line. Here's the code in Python 3.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

def merge(*dicts):
    return { k: reduce(lambda d, x: x.get(k, d), dicts, None) for k in reduce(or_, map(lambda x: x.keys(), dicts), set()) }
```

Tests

```
>>> d = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16}
>>> d_letters = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j', 10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm', 13: 'n', 14: 'o', 15: 'p', 16: 'q', 17: 'r', 18: 's', 19: 't', 20: 'u', 21: 'v', 22: 'w', 23: 'x', 24: 'y', 25: 'z', 26: 'A', 27: 'B', 28: 'C', 29: 'D', 30: 'E', 31: 'F', 32: 'G', 33: 'H', 34: 'I', 35: 'J', 36: 'K', 37: 'L', 38: 'M', 39: 'N', 40: 'O', 41: 'P', 42: 'Q', 43: 'R', 44: 'S', 45: 'T', 46: 'U', 47: 'V', 48: 'W', 49: 'X', 50: 'Y', 51: 'Z'}
>>> merge(d, d_letters)
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j', 10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm', 13: 'n', 14: 'o', 15: 'p', 16: 'q', 17: 'r', 18: 's', 19: 't', 20: 'u', 21: 'v', 22: 'w', 23: 'x', 24: 'y', 25: 'z', 26: 'A', 27: 'B', 28: 'C', 29: 'D', 30: 'E', 31: 'F', 32: 'G', 33: 'H', 34: 'I', 35: 'J', 36: 'K', 37: 'L', 38: 'M', 39: 'N', 40: 'O', 41: 'P', 42: 'Q', 43: 'R', 44: 'S', 45: 'T', 46: 'U', 47: 'V', 48: 'W', 49: 'X', 50: 'Y', 51: 'Z'}
>>> merge(d_letters, d)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j', 10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm', 13: 'n', 14: 'o', 15: 'p', 16: 'q', 17: 'r', 18: 's', 19: 't', 20: 'u', 21: 'v', 22: 'w', 23: 'x', 24: 'y', 25: 'z', 26: 'A', 27: 'B', 28: 'C', 29: 'D', 30: 'E', 31: 'F', 32: 'G', 33: 'H', 34: 'I', 35: 'J', 36: 'K', 37: 'L', 38: 'M', 39: 'N', 40: 'O', 41: 'P', 42: 'Q', 43: 'R', 44: 'S', 45: 'T', 46: 'U', 47: 'V', 48: 'W', 49: 'X', 50: 'Y', 51: 'Z'}
>>> merge(d)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16}
>>> merge(d_letters)
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j', 10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm', 13: 'n', 14: 'o', 15: 'p', 16: 'q', 17: 'r', 18: 's', 19: 't', 20: 'u', 21: 'v', 22: 'w', 23: 'x', 24: 'y', 25: 'z', 26: 'A', 27: 'B', 28: 'C', 29: 'D', 30: 'E', 31: 'F', 32: 'G', 33: 'H', 34: 'I', 35: 'J', 36: 'K', 37: 'L', 38: 'M', 39: 'N', 40: 'O', 41: 'P', 42: 'Q', 43: 'R', 44: 'S', 45: 'T', 46: 'U', 47: 'V', 48: 'W', 49: 'X', 50: 'Y', 51: 'Z'}
>>> merge()
{}
```

It works for arbitrary number of dictionary arguments. Were there any duplicate keys in those dictionary, the key from the rightmost dictionary in the argument list wins.

Comment: A simple loop with an `.update` call in it (`merged={}` followed by `for d in dict: merged.update(d)`) would be shorter, more readable and more efficient.

Comment: Or if you really want to use `reduce` and `lambda`s, how about `return reduce(lambda x, y: x.update(y) or x, dicts, {})`?

Comment: You can try out your code in the shell and see if it's correct. What I was trying to do is to write a function that can take various number of dictionary arguments with the same functionality. It's better not to use x.update(y) under the lambda, because it always returns _None_. And I am trying to write a more general function _merge\_with_ that take various number of dictionary argument and deal with duplicate keys with the supplied function. Once I am done, I'll post it in another thread where the solution is more relevant.

Comment: Here's [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560840/python-merge-dictionaries-with-custom-merge-function/28381494#28381494) where I wrote the more general solution. Welcome and have a look.

Answer (score 3):

[Trey Hunner has a nice blog post](http://treyhunner.com/2016/02/how-to-merge-dictionaries-in-python/) outlining several options for merging multiple dictionaries, including (for python3.3+) [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) and [dictionary unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, as stated above, using `d2.update(d1)` is the best approach and that you can also copy `d2` first if you still need it.

Although, I want to point out that `dict(d1, **d2)` is actually a bad way to merge dictionnaries in general since keyword arguments need to be strings, thus it will fail if you have a `dict` such as:

```
{1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}
```