# Python merge dictionaries with custom merge function

Tags: python, dictionary, coding-style

I want to merge two dictionaries A and B such that the result contains:

- All pairs from A where key is unique to A
- All pairs from B where key is unique to B
- f(valueA, valueB) where the same key exists in both A and B

For example:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x * y

A = {1:1, 2:3}
B = {7:3, 2:2}

C = merge(A, B)
```

Output:

```
{1:1, 7:3, 2:6}
```

It feels like there should be a nice one-liner to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [dictionary views](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to achieve this; the [`dict.viewkeys()` result](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) acts like a set and let you do intersections and symmetrical differences:

```
def merge(A, B, f):
    # Start with symmetric difference; keys either in A or B, but not both
    merged = {k: A.get(k, B.get(k)) for k in A.viewkeys() ^ B.viewkeys()}
    # Update with `f()` applied to the intersection
    merged.update({k: f(A[k], B[k]) for k in A.viewkeys() & B.viewkeys()})
    return merged
```

In Python 3, the `.viewkeys()` method has been renamed to `.keys()`, replacing the old `.keys()` functionality (which in Python 2 returs a list).

The above `merge()` method is the generic solution which works for any given `f()`.

Demo:

```
>>> def f(x, y):
...     return x * y
... 
>>> A = {1:1, 2:3}
>>> B = {7:3, 2:2}
>>> merge(A, B, f)
{1: 1, 2: 6, 7: 3}
>>> merge(A, B, lambda a, b: '{} merged with {}'.format(a, b))
{1: 1, 2: '3 merged with 2', 7: 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stealing this (`A.get(k, B.get(k))` snippet from @MartijnPieters

```
>>> def f(x, y):
        return x * y

>>> A = {1:1, 2:3}
>>> B = {7:3, 2:2}
>>> {k: f(A[k], B[k]) if k in A and k in B else A.get(k, B.get(k))
     for k in A.viewkeys() | B.viewkeys()}
{1: 1, 2: 6, 7: 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution code in Python 3 for the general case.

I first wrote the *merge* function and then extend it to the more general *merge_with* function, which takes a function and various number of dictionaries. Were there any duplicate keys in those dictionaries, apply the supplied function to the values whose keys are duplicate.

The *merge* function can be redefined using the *merge_with* function, as in the case of *merger* function. The name *merger* means to merge them all and keep the rightmost values, were there any duplicates. So does the *mergel* function, which keep the leftmost.

All the functions here — *merge*, *merge_with*, *mergel*, and *merger* — are generic in the case that they take arbitrary number of dictionary arguments. Specifically, *merge_with* must take as argument a function compatible with the data to which it will apply.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

def merge(*dicts):
    return { k: reduce(lambda d, x: x.get(k, d), dicts, None)
             for k in reduce(or_, map(lambda x: x.keys(), dicts), set()) }

def merge_with(f, *dicts):
    return { k: (lambda x: f(*x) if len(x)>1 else x[0])([ d[k] for d in dicts
                                                          if k in d ])
             for k in reduce(or_, map(lambda x: x.keys(), dicts), set()) }

mergel = lambda *dicts: merge_with(lambda *x: x[0], *dicts)

merger = lambda *dicts: merge_with(lambda *x: x[-1], *dicts)
```

Tests

```
>>> squares = { k:k*k for k in range(4) }
>>> squares
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9}
>>> cubes = { k:k**3 for k in range(2,6) }
>>> cubes
{2: 8, 3: 27, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> merger(squares, cubes)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 8, 3: 27, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> merger(cubes, squares)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> mergel(squares, cubes)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> mergel(cubes, squares)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 8, 3: 27, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> merge(squares, cubes)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 8, 3: 27, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> merge(cubes, squares)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> merge_with(lambda x, y: x+y, squares, cubes)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 12, 3: 36, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> merge_with(lambda x, y: x*y, squares, cubes)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 32, 3: 243, 4: 64, 5: 125}
```

**Update**

After I wrote the above, I find there's another way to do it.

```
from functools import reduce

def merge(*dicts):
    return reduce(lambda d1, d2: reduce(lambda d, t:
                                        dict(list(d.items())+[t]),
                                        d2.items(), d1),
                  dicts, {})

def merge_with(f, *dicts):
    return reduce(lambda d1, d2: reduce(lambda d, t:
                                        dict(list(d.items()) +
                                             [(t[0], f(d[t[0]], t[1])
                                               if t[0] in d else
                                               t[1])]),
                                        d2.items(), d1),
                  dicts, {})

mergel = lambda *dicts: merge_with(lambda x, y: x, *dicts)
merger = lambda *dicts: merge_with(lambda x, y: y, *dicts)
```

Notice that the definitions for *mergel* and *merger* using *merge_with* have been changed with new functions as first arguments. The *f* function must now be binary. The tests provided above still works. Here are some more tests to show the generality of those functions.

```
>>> merge() == {}
True
>>> merge(squares) == squares
True
>>> merge(cubes) == cubes
True
>>> mergel() == {}
True
>>> mergel(squares) == squares
True
>>> mergel(cubes) == cubes
True
>>> merger() == {}
True
>>> merger(squares) == squares
True
>>> merger(cubes) == cubes
True
>>> merge_with(lambda x, y: x+y, squares, cubes, squares)
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 16, 3: 45, 4: 64, 5: 125}
>>> merge_with(lambda x, y: x*y, squares, cubes, squares)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 128, 3: 2187, 4: 64, 5: 125}
```

Comment: @stein: I use `reduce` and `*x` for the reason of extensibility. For your test case with two dicts, I would rather write `{k: f(A.get(k, 0), B.get(k, 0)) for k in A.keys() | B.keys()}` which is still the worst among others, but not significantly worser.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(list(A.items()) + list(B.items()) + [(k,f(A[k],B[k])) for k in A.keys() & B.keys()])
```

is in my opinion the shortest and most readable code in Python 3. I derived it from DhruvPathak's answer and realised that optimising it leads to kampu's answer specialised for Python 3:

```
dict(itertools.chain(A.items(), B.items(), ((k,f(A[k],B[k])) for k in A.keys() & B.keys())))
```

I compared all of the answers here for performance, and got this ranking:

- `mergeLZ: 34.0ms` (Lei Zhao, quite bulky one-liner)
- `mergeJK: 11.6ms` (jamylak)
- `mergeMP: 11.5ms` (Martijn Pieters, almost a one-liner)
- `mergeDP:  6.9ms` (DhruvPathak)
- `mergeDS:  6.8ms` (1st one-liner above)
- `mergeK3:  5.2ms` (kampu = 2nd one-liner above)
- `mergeS3:  3.5ms` (imperative, not a one-liner)

where the latter mergeS3 is a naive, imperative, multi-line code. I'm disappointed that the old ways prevail when it comes to performance. This test is for simple integer keys and values, but the ranking is quite similar for big string keys and values. Obviously mileage may vary by dictionary size and amount of key overlap (1/3 in my test). By the way, Lei Zhao's second implementation, which I haven't tried to understand, seems to have abysmal performance, ~1000 times slower.

The code:

```
import functools 
import itertools
import operator
import timeit

def t(x): # transform keys and values
    return x # str(x) * 8

def f(x,y): # merge values
    return x + y

N = 10000
A = {t(k*2): t(k*22) for k in range(N)}
B = {t(k*3): t(k*33) for k in range(N)}

def check(AB):
    assert(len(A) == N)
    assert(len(B) == N)
    assert(len(AB) == 16666)
    assert(AB[t(0)] == f(t(0), t(0)))
    assert(t(1) not in AB)
    assert(AB[t(2)] == t(1*22))
    assert(AB[t(3)] == t(1*33))
    assert(AB[t(4)] == t(2*22))
    assert(t(5) not in AB)
    assert(AB[t(6)] == f(t(3*22), t(2*33)))
    assert(t(7) not in AB)
    assert(AB[t(8)] == t(4*22))
    assert(AB[t(9)] == t(3*33))

def mergeLZ(): # Lei Zhao
    merged = {k: (lambda x: f(*x) if len(x)>1 else x[0])([ d[k] for d in [A, B]
                                                          if k in d ])
             for k in functools.reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda x: x.keys(), [A, B]), set()) }
    check(merged)
def mergeJK(): # jamylak
    merged = {k: f(A[k], B[k]) if k in A and k in B else A.get(k, B.get(k)) for k in A.keys() | B.keys()}
    check(merged)
def mergeMP(): # Martijn Pieters
    merged = {k: A.get(k, B.get(k)) for k in A.keys() ^ B.keys()}
    merged.update({k: f(A[k], B[k]) for k in A.keys() & B.keys()})
    check(merged)
def mergeDP(): # DhruvPathak
    merged = dict([(k,v) for k,v in A.items()] + [ (k,v) if k not in A else (k,f(A[k],B[k])) for k,v in B.items()])
    check(merged)
def mergeDS(): # more elegant (IMO) variation on DhruvPathak
    merged = dict(list(A.items()) + list(B.items()) + [(k,f(A[k],B[k])) for k in A.keys() & B.keys()])
    check(merged)
def mergeK3(): # kampu adapted to Python 3
    merged = dict(itertools.chain(A.items(), B.items(), ((k,f(A[k],B[k])) for k in A.keys() & B.keys())))
    check(merged)
def mergeS3(): # "naive" imperative way
    merged = A.copy()
    for k,v in B.items():
        if k in A:
            merged[k] = f(A[k], v)
        else:
            merged[k] = v
    check(merged)

for m in [mergeLZ, mergeJK, mergeMP, mergeDP, mergeDS, mergeK3, mergeS3]:
    print("{}: {:4.1f}ms".format(m.__name__, timeit.timeit(m, number=1000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def f(x,y):
...     return x*y
... 
>>> dict([(k,v) for k,v in A.items()] + [ (k,v) if k not in A else (k,f(A[k],B[k])) for k,v in B.items()])
{1: 1, 2: 6, 7: 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

intersection = set(A.keys()).intersection(B.keys())
C = dict(chain(A.items(), B.items(), ((k, f(A[k], B[k])) for k in intersection)))
```

Could technically be made into a oneliner.
Works in both Py2 and Py3. If you only care about Py3, you can rewrite the 'intersection' line to:

```
intersection = A.keys() & B.keys()
```

(for Py2-only, use `A.viewkeys() & B.viewkeys()` instead.)

Comment: You are only processing keys that are either in A or B, not in both, and **ignoring** the intersecting keys and `f()`.

Comment: This also won't work for keys in `A` that are `None`, numeric 0 or empty sequences, which test as `False`.

Comment: Don't use `!= None`, rather use `not is None`. This still will fail for keys whose value is `None`: `A = {1: None}`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I fixed that while you were commenting. (except for None) Looks like I totally misread the question though, so I'll try to fix that.

Comment: The `intersection` calculation isn't as efficient as it could be (`.viewkeys()` returns a set-like object, using `&` on those will give you an intersection too with less work for the interpreter), but at least now you don't mess up `None` values anymore. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's true, however the API is incompatible between Py2 / Py3 (`viewkeys()` is `keys()` in Py3) , so I opted not to use that.

Comment: for code that straddles Python 2.7 and 3.x, I just test for the version here. `keys = dict.keys if PY3 else dict.viewkeys` and `keys(A) & keys(B)` is a good trick.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach that is (imho) more readable for users that come from a background in functional programming

```
def merge_with(f):
    def merge(a,b):
        g = lambda l: [x for x in l if x is not None]  
        keys = a.keys() | b.keys()
        return {key:f(*g([a.get(key), b.get(key)])) for key in keys}
    return merge
```

Applying this to the OP's example:

```
A = {1:1, 2:3}
B = {7:3, 2:2}
merge_with(lambda x,y=1: x*y)(A,B)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def merge_dict(dict1,dict2):
    dict1={1:'red'}
    dict2={2:'black',3:'yellow'}
    dict1.update(dict2)
    print 'dict3 =',dict1

merge_dict(dict1,dict2)
```

**Output:**

```
dict3 = {1: 'red', 2: 'black', 3: 'yellow'}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question. It doesn't even mention the function f to merge values.