# Merge list of dictionaries based on matching values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a set of data similar to this:

```
trades =  [{'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 2200}, 
            {'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 500}, 
            {'ORDERID': 456, 'LEAVESQTY': 100}, 
            {'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 300}]
```

I am looking for an efficient way to find the lowest value of `LEAVESQTY` for each matching `ORDERID` in the list of dictionaries.

For example, my desired result for this example would be:

```
output = [{'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 5000},
          {'ORDERID': 456, 'LEAVESQTY': 100},
          {'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 300}]
```

I have tried to apply the same approach as similar questions that merge dictionaries based on matching key values, i'm just having trouble merging based on values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560840/python-merge-dictionaries-with-custom-merge-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to construct a dictionary to list mapping.

Then use a dictionary comprehension to calculate the minimum of each list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

trades =  [{'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 2200}, 
           {'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 500}, 
           {'ORDERID': 456, 'LEAVESQTY': 100}, 
           {'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 300}]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in trades:
    d[item['ORDERID']].append(item['LEAVESQTY'])

res = [{'ORDERID': k, 'LEAVESQTY': min(v)} for k, v in d.items()]

[{'LEAVESQTY': 500, 'ORDERID': 123},
 {'LEAVESQTY': 100, 'ORDERID': 456},
 {'LEAVESQTY': 300, 'ORDERID': 789}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `sorted` and `toolz.unique`. The idea is to sort by `LEAVESQTY` and then drop duplicates by `ORDERID`.

If you don't have access to the [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, the logic is identical to the `unique_everseen` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) found in the `itertools` docs.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from toolz import unique

trades =  [{'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 2200}, 
           {'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 500}, 
           {'ORDERID': 456, 'LEAVESQTY': 100}, 
           {'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 300}]

sorter = sorted(trades, key=itemgetter('LEAVESQTY'))
res = list(unique(sorter, key=itemgetter('ORDERID')))

print(res)

[{'LEAVESQTY': 100, 'ORDERID': 456},
 {'LEAVESQTY': 300, 'ORDERID': 789},
 {'LEAVESQTY': 500, 'ORDERID': 123}]
```

Comment: Quite fast, impressive .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
d = {}

trades =  [{'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 2200}, 
            {'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 500}, 
            {'ORDERID': 456, 'LEAVESQTY': 100}, 
            {'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 300}]

for i in trades:
    if i['ORDERID'] not in d:
        d[i["ORDERID"]] = i
    else:
        if d[i["ORDERID"]]["LEAVESQTY"] > i["LEAVESQTY"]:
            d[i["ORDERID"]]["LEAVESQTY"] = i["LEAVESQTY"]
print(d.values())
```

**Output:**

```
[{'ORDERID': 456, 'LEAVESQTY': 100}, {'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 500}, {'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 300}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

common = lambda x: x['ORDERID']

grouped = groupby(sorted(trades, key=common), key=common)

output = [min(group) for key, group in grouped]

output
#[{'LEAVESQTY': 500, 'ORDERID': 123},
# {'LEAVESQTY': 100, 'ORDERID': 456},
# {'LEAVESQTY': 300, 'ORDERID': 789}]
```

**EDIT**

The sorted is necessary as @jpp suggested for this to work as it will otherwise produce duplicate keys if the data looks like this:

```
#trades =  [{'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 400},
#           {'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 2200}, 
#            {'ORDERID': 123, 'LEAVESQTY': 500}, 
#            {'ORDERID': 456, 'LEAVESQTY': 100}, 
#            {'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 300},
#            {'ORDERID': 789, 'LEAVESQTY': 150}]
```

Comment: @jpp Didn't account for that, you are absolutely correct. Will edit