# Merging values attached to like keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

What i am trying to do is take a text file and return a dictionary of the anagrams (words that make a new word when rearranged alphabetically) in the file. So if the file contained the words dub and bud, then the code should create a key bdu and attach the strings dub and bud to them in a tuple or list or what have you.

Now my code outputs exactly what i want, except that instead of one key with multiple values, im getting identical keys for every value. To draw back to my previous example, i get the key bdu for dub, then another bdu key for bud. How would i remove identical keys and merge key values to one key?

```
def anagrams(f):
    '''takes a file and returns a list of anagrams in the file'''
    wordget = open(f).read().lower().split()
    dic = {}
    for w in wordget:
        if ("".join(sortword(w))) in wordget:
            dic = {("".join(sortword(w))):w}
            for key in dic.keys():
                print "'%s': %s" % (key, dic[key])
    return None
```

Any help would be appreciated. I hope to come up with a solution that runs quick too, even with files containing tens of thousands of words (like books)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I merge dictionaries together in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799064/how-do-i-merge-dictionaries-together-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Python's [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) type in the collections package is useful for this kind of thing.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
answer = defaultdict(list)
for word in open(filename).read().lower().split():
    answer[''.join(sorted(word))].append(word)
pprint(answer)
```

The defaultdict initialization accepts a function which initializes an object. In this case we initialize an empty list which we can immediately append.

You may also find the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module useful. It'll nicely format your lists of words.

Comment: Glad I could help, Alex. And welcome to StackOverflow. PS. Remember to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the green check mark to the upper left of the answer. That's a big part of the community.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
dic = {("".join(sortword(w))):w}
```

is replacing `dic` with a new dictionary each time. You should be inserting keys or appending to lists instead

```
for w in wordget:
    key = ''.join(sorted(word))
    if key in dic:
        dic[key].append(word)
    else:
        dic[key] = [word]
 return dic
```

The `if`/`else` block can be tidied up using defaultdict as in GrantJ's answer