# How to create a list of dicts into a single dict with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large list of dictionaries, each with exactly one entry and with unique keys, and I want to 'combine' them into a single dict with python 3.8.

So here is an example that actually works:

```
mylist = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
mydict = {list(x.keys())[0]:list(x.values())[0] for x in mylist}
```

which gives as result the expected output:

```
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

But it looks ugly and not quite pythonic. Is there a better **one-line solution** to this problem?

This is similar to the question asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799064/how-do-i-merge-dictionaries-together-in-python), but in my example I am looking for an answer (1) to merge many dicts together and (2) for a one-line solution. That makes my question different from the question already asked.

Comment: You also saw the *second* duplicate…? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3494906/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydict = { k:v for elt in mylist for k, v in elt.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, simple and effective.

```
mylist = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
result = {}
for d in mylist:
    result.update(d)
```

Result

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```