# How to check & supply missing data in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am pulling data from an API and outputting it in influx line format.  However, sometimes there is data missing,  Rather than supplying a null value, the API omits that field.  That causes this code to die.

```
    for serial in SERIALS[site]:
        r = requests.get(f"{BASE_API_URL}/equipment/{site}/{serial}/data", {
            'startTime': format_datetime_url(startTime),
            'endTime': format_datetime_url(endTime),
            'api_key': SETTING_API_KEY
        },
            timeout=REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
            
        # Parse request
        for value in r.json()['data']['telemetries']:
            date = value['date']
            print(
                f'data,site={site},sn={serial} I_Temp={value["temperature"]},I_AC_Energy_WH={value["totalEnergy"]},I_AC_Power={value["totalActivePower"]} {to_unix_timestamp(date)}',
                flush=False)
    return True
```

This code dies with a KeyError if any of the fields in `value` are missing.  I can add in something like this just before the print statement:

```
            if not 'temperature' in value:
                value["temperature"] = ""
            if not 'totalEnergy' in value:
                value["totalEnergy"] = ""
            if not 'totalActivePower' in value:
                value["totalActivePower"] = ""
```

but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Maybe try *value.get(...)* not sure it's more elegant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a stable output like the text below that contains following *metric*s or a default value like empty-string `''` if missing from your retrieved JSON telemetries:

1. temperature
2. totalEnergy
3. totalActivePower
4. date

There are two simple ways to achieve this. Choose the most elegant or readable.

#### Default dict merged with present values

Then you can simply create a **default** `data_points` dict and use dict's [`dict.update(with_other)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method to overwrite with the present response-key/values in `telemetries`:

```py
# Parse request and print data points with defaults
for telemetries in r.json()['data']['telemetries']:
    # default data points to be shown if not present in retrieved telemetries
    data_points = {'temperature': 'N/A', 'totalEnergy': 'N/A', 'totalActivePower': 'N/A', 'date': 'N/A'}
    # overwrite defaults with retrieved
    data_points.update(telemetries)

    text = f"data,site={site},sn={serial} I_Temp={data_points['temperature']},I_AC_Energy_WH={data_points['totalEnergy']},I_AC_Power={data_points['totalActivePower']} {to_unix_timestamp(data_points['date'])}"
    print(text, flush=False)
```

Note: I used `'N/A'` instead empty-string as default value which signals that the telemetry data point is not available.

See
[How do I merge dictionaries together in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799064/how-do-i-merge-dictionaries-together-in-python/2799075#2799075)

#### Recipe to prevent key-error and return default

Like suggested by [Daniel Hao's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379818/how-to-check-supply-missing-data/73381121#comment129588821_73379818):

The dict's method [`dict.get(key, default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) can be used to supply a default value if the key is missing:

> Return the value for *key* if key is in the dictionary, else *default*. If default is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

You can use it directly in your f-string:

```py
print(f'data,site={site},sn={serial} I_Temp={value.get("temperature","")},I_AC_Energy_WH={value.get("totalEnergy","")},I_AC_Power={value.get("totalActivePower","")} {to_unix_timestamp(date)}', flush=False)
```

This hides the defaulting-behavior inside the f-string so that the code and its intention might be harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) with default values for your fields, implement a method to output it into Influx line method, create them from your `dict` objects, and then just call their format method. This is just an example that doesn't use all the fields you showed, but it should work for demo purposes:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TelemetryPoint:
    temperature: str = ""
    totalEnergy: str = ""
    totalActivePower: str = ""

    def influx_line_format(self) -> str:
        parts = [
            "data",
            f"I_Temp={self.temperature}",
            f"I_AC_Energy_WH={self.totalEnergy}",
            f"I_AC_Power={self.totalActivePower}"
        ]
   
        return ",".join(parts)

# sample data is missing totalEnergy and totalActivePower
sample_data = { "temperature": "192" }
data_point = TelemetryPoint(**sample_data)
print(data_point.influx_line_format(), flush=False)
```

And the output is...

```
data,I_Temp=192,I_AC_Energy_WH=,I_AC_Power=
```

---

You could also pre-process the dictionaries you get back so that any missing values are populated.

```
def hydrate_datapoint(data_point) -> None:
    expected_keys = [ "totalEnergy", "temperature", "totalActivePower" ]
    for k in expected_keys:
        if k not in data_point:
            data_point[k] = ""

sample_data = {"temperature": "192"}
hydrate_datapoint(sample_data)
print(sample_data)
```

And this would populate any empty fields:

```
{'temperature': '192', 'totalEnergy': '', 'totalActivePower': ''}
```